# MuleSoft RTF: Get Version of the API Deployed

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

We are using MuleSoft RTF EKS on AWS. Managing about 40+ apps and we want to see which version of the app is running in different environments.

I see mulesoft provided rtf-core-usage-calculator (https://github.com/mulesoft-catalyst/rtf-core-usage-calculator) which provides all the apis in each environment with CPU/Memory BUT it doesn't tell what version of the api is running (I did looked at runtime manager rest api as well but couldn't get the version).

Is there a way to get what version of the api is deployed/running on RTF ??

[image]